# Reactive Programming: Spring WebFlux: How to build a chain of micro-service calls?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

`Spring Boot` Application:

a `@RestController` receives the following payload:

```
{
  "cartoon": "The Little Mermaid",
  "characterNames": ["Ariel", "Prince Eric", "Sebastian", "Flounder"]
}
```

I need to process it in the following way:

1. Get the unique Id for each character name: make an HTTP call to "cartoon-characters" microservice, that returns ids by names
2. Transform data received by the controller: 
   replace character names with appropriate ids that were received on the previous step from "cartoon-characters" microservice.
      `{
       "cartoon": "The Little Mermaid",
       "characterIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
       }`
3. Send an HTTP POST request to "cartoon-db" microservice with transformed data.
4. Map the response from "cartoon-db" to the internal representation that is the controller return value.

The problem that I got:

I need to implement all these steps using the paradigm of `Reactive Programming` (non-blocking\async processing) with `Spring WebFlux` (`Mono`|`Flux`) and `Spring Reactive WebClient` - but I have zero experience with that stack, trying to read about it as much as I can, plus googling a lot but still, have a bunch of unanswered questions, for example:

**Q1**. I have already configured reactive webClient that sends a request to "cartoon-characters" microservice:

```
      public Mono<Integer> getCartoonCharacterIdbyName(String characterName) {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://cartoon-characters").build()
        .get()
        .uri("/character/{characterName}", characterName)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Integer.class);
  }
```

As you may see, I have got a list of cartoon character names and for each of them I need to call `getCartoonCharacterIdbyName(String name)` method, I am not sure that the right option to call it in series, believe the right option: parallel execution.

Wrote the following method:

```
  public List<Integer> getCartoonCharacterIds(List<String> names) {
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.fromStream(names.stream())
    .flatMap(this::getCartoonCharacterIdbyName);

return StreamSupport.stream(flux.toIterable().spliterator(), false)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

}

but I have doubts, that this code does parallel `WebClient` execution and also, code calls `flux.toIterable()` that block the thread, so with this implementation I lost non-blocking mechanism.

Are my assumptions correct?

How do I need to rewrite it to having parallelism and non-blocking?

**Q2.**
Is it technically possible to transform input data received by the controller (I mean replace names with ids) in reactive style: when we operate with `Flux<Integer>` characterIds, but not with the `List<Integer>` of characterIds?

**Q3.** Is it potentially possible to get not just transformed Data object, but Mono<> after **step 2** that can be consumed by another WebClient in **Step 3**?

Comment: Instead of toIterable you should use collectList operator which is non-blocking and gives you a Mono<List>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it's a good question since understanding the WebFlux, or project reactor framework, when it comes to chaining micro-services requires a couple of steps.

The first is to realize that a `WebClient` should take a publisher in and return a publisher. Extrapolate this to 4 different method signatures to help with thinking.

- Mono -> Mono
- Flux -> Flux
- Mono -> Flux
- Flux -> Mono

For sure, in all cases, it is just Publisher->Publisher, but leave that until you understand things better. The first two are obvious, and you just use `.map(...)` to handle objects in the flow, but you need to learn how to handle the second two. As commented above, going from Flux->Mono could be done with `.collectList()`, or also with `.reduce(...)`. Going from Mono->Flux seems to generally be done with `.flatMapMany` or `.flatMapIterable` or some variation of that. There are probably other techniques. You should never use `.block()` in any WebFlux code, and generally you will get a runtime error if you try to do so.

In your example you want to go to

- (Mono->Flux)->(Flux->Flux)->(Flux->Flux)

As you said, you want

- Mono->Flux->Flux

The second part is to understand about chaining Flows. You could do

- p3(p2(p1(object)));

Which would chain p1->p2->p3, but I always found it more understandable to make a "Service Layer" instead.

- o2 = p1(object);
- o3 = p2(o2);
- result = p3(o3);

This code is just much easier to read and maintain and, with some maturity, you come to understand the worth of that statement.

The only problem I had with your example was doing a `Flux<String>` with `WebClient` as a `@RequestBody`. Doesn't work. See [WebClient bodyToFlux(String.class) for string list doesn't separate individual values](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22662). Other than that, it's a pretty straightforward application. You'll find when you debug it that it gets to the `.subscribe(System.out::println)` line before it gets to the `Flux<Integer> ids = mapNamesToIds(fn)` line. This is because the Flow is setup before it is executed. Takes a while to understand this but it is the point of the project reactor framework.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    Map<Integer, CartoonCharacter> characters;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        String[] names = new String[] {"Ariel", "Prince Eric", "Sebastian", "Flounder"};
        characters = Arrays.asList( new CartoonCharacter[] {
                new CartoonCharacter(names[0].hashCode(), names[0], "Mermaid"), 
                new CartoonCharacter(names[1].hashCode(), names[1], "Human"), 
                new CartoonCharacter(names[2].hashCode(), names[2], "Crustacean"), 
                new CartoonCharacter(names[3].hashCode(), names[3], "Fish")} 
        )
        .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(CartoonCharacter::getId, Function.identity()));
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CartoonRequest cr = CartoonRequest.builder()
        .cartoon("The Little Mermaid")
        .characterNames(Arrays.asList(names))
        .build();
        thisLocalClient
            .post()
            .uri("cartoonDetails")
            .body(Mono.just(cr), CartoonRequest.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(CartoonCharacter.class)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient localClient() {
        return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/demo/");
    }

    @Autowired
    WebClient thisLocalClient;

    @PostMapping("cartoonDetails")
    Flux<CartoonCharacter> getDetails(@RequestBody Mono<CartoonRequest> cartoonRequest) {
        Flux<StringWrapper> fn = cartoonRequest.flatMapIterable(cr->cr.getCharacterNames().stream().map(StringWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        Flux<Integer> ids = mapNamesToIds(fn);
        Flux<CartoonCharacter> details = mapIdsToDetails(ids);
        return details;
    }
    //  Service Layer Methods
    private Flux<Integer> mapNamesToIds(Flux<StringWrapper> names) {
        return thisLocalClient
            .post()
            .uri("findIds")
            .body(names, StringWrapper.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Integer.class);
    }
    private Flux<CartoonCharacter> mapIdsToDetails(Flux<Integer> ids) {
        return thisLocalClient
            .post()
            .uri("findDetails")
            .body(ids, Integer.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(CartoonCharacter.class);
    }
    // Services
    @PostMapping("findIds")
    Flux<Integer> getIds(@RequestBody Flux<StringWrapper> names) {
        return names.map(name->name.getString().hashCode());
    }
    @PostMapping("findDetails")
    Flux<CartoonCharacter> getDetails(@RequestBody Flux<Integer> ids) {
        return ids.map(characters::get);
    }
}
```

Also:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class StringWrapper {
    private String string;
}
@Data
@Builder
public class CartoonRequest {
    private String cartoon;
    private List<String> characterNames;
}
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CartoonCharacter {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String species;
}
```