# Chained reactive components invocation

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a list of following objects with method returning reactive type `Mono<?>`:

```java
interface GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod {

    Mono<String> execute();
}

class ReactiveGuysInvocator {

    Mono<String> executeAllGuys(List<GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod> guysToInvoke) {
        ???
    }
}
```

And I need to invoke all the guys one by one (`n`'s guy result is `n+1`'s guy argument), but I'm not sure how can I iterate over such list.
I thought of `flatMap`ing next guy in a while loop:

```java
public interface GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod {

    Mono<String> execute(String string);
}

class ReactiveGuysInvocator {

    Mono<String> executeAllGuys(List<GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod> guysToExecute) {
        ListIterator<GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod> iterator = guysToExecute.listIterator();
        Mono<String> currentResult = Mono.just("start");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod guyToInvoke = iterator.next();
            currentResult = currentResult.flatMap(guyToInvoke::execute)
                    .doOnNext(object -> System.out.println("Executed!"))
                    .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Error"));
        }
        return currentResult;
    }
}
```

But this approach seems to be completely incorrect.
Does anyone know how could I implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: `flatMap` can be easily abused. Make sure that you are doing `asynchronous` work when using `flatMap`. Mostly, it seems to me, that you can do pretty well with a minimum of `Mono.just`.

`Flatmap` is what you have to do with the constraints you provide.

```
executeAllGuys(Arrays.asList(new GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod[] {
        (s)->Mono.just(s+"1"), 
        (s)->Mono.just(s+"2"), 
        (s)->Mono.just(s+"3")})) 
.subscribe(System.out::println);

Mono<String> executeAllGuys(List<GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod> guysToExecute) {
    // your flow is starting here
    Mono<String> stringMono = Mono.just("start");
    for ( GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod guyToInvoke: guysToExecute) {
        stringMono = stringMono.flatMap(guyToInvoke::execute);
    }
    return stringMono;
}
```

Just look at all those `Mono.just` calls. Why do you want to create N+1 flows to do the job? The real problem is you're creating a new flow every time you execute the interface method. `Flatmap` stops the current flow and starts a new one with the publisher returned by the `flatMap` method. Try to think `reactive` and treat the whole business like a stream. There is no `flatMap` in `Streams`. A reactive execution should be done on only a single flow.

A `Mono<String> execute(String string)` is not a reactive component. It is a reactive producer. A `Mono<String> execute(Mono<String> string)` is a reactive component.

1. Make your interface *more* reactive by taking a `Mono` in and returning a `Mono`.  Your application is doing a `map` conversion on at each step. This is "chaining reactive components".

   executeAllGuys(Arrays.asList(new GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod[] {
   (s)->s.map(str->str+"1"),
   (s)->s.map(str->str+"2"),
   (s)->s.map(str->str+"3")}))
   .subscribe(System.out::println);

   Mono executeAllGuys(List guysToExecute) {
   // your flow is starting here
   Mono stringMono = Mono.just("start");
   for ( GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod guyToInvoke: guysToExecute) {
   stringMono = guyToInvoke.execute(stringMono);
   }
   return stringMono;
   }

   interface GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod {
   Mono execute(Mono string);
   }
2. Make your interface *less* reactive but make your application *more* reactive by using a `Flux` instead of a list. You will then have to use `reduce` to convert a Flux to a Mono. Your application is doing a Map/Reduce function. I don't think a `Flux` will guarantee execution order of the elements in the flow but it could executeAllGuys more efficiently.

   // your flow is starting here
   executeAllGuys(Flux.just(
   (s)->s+"1",
   (s)->s+"2",
   (s)->s+"3"))
   .subscribe(System.out::println);

   Mono executeAllGuys(Flux guysToExecute) {
   return guysToExecute.reduce("start", (str, guyToInvoke)->guyToInvoke.execute(str));
   }
   interface GuyWithReactiveReturnTypeMethod {
   String execute(String string);
   }

Reference: [Reactive Programming: Spring WebFlux: How to build a chain of micro-service calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858717/reactive-programming-spring-webflux-how-to-build-a-chain-of-micro-service-call/60907153#60907153)

Comment: `Never use flatMap unless you are absolutely, and probably incorrectly, convinced that you have to. Don't forget your Streams programming.` Flatmaps perfectly fine to use, not sure why you think it's a big issue. Tons of the actual reactive reference documentation uses it for many different scenarios.

Comment: @123 And tons of bad reactive documentation out there. Probably a misconception on your part.

Comment: Probably not, are you trying to say projectreactor's own documentation of their own code is bad? Do you have any sources or references for your assertions? (Other than yourself...)

Comment: Very immature for someone who presumes to be an adult . Docs predominately use .map. along with .flatMap for a misguided example of a "favoriteService". Start by looking at the WebClient for interfacing with "favoriteService". WebCient takes a publisher and returns a publisher. The essential definition of a reactive component.