# Trying to Send list of string in post request using webClient in spring

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, webclient, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

- I am trying to send a list of strings using webClient but I am
  getting an exception.
- I used `Flux.fromIterable(strList)` but it merged all the data before
  sending, because of that instead of a list of strings I received
  combined single string on mapping class.

  ```
   List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
               str.add("korba");
               str.add("raipur");
               str.add("bhilai");

     Flux<Object> responsePost = webClient.build()
                        .post()
                        .uri(url)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .body(Flux.fromIterable(str), String.class)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToFlux(Object.class);
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a `Flux` of strings because it combines them into a single string. See,

[WebClient bodyToFlux(String.class) for string list doesn't separate individual value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22662)

You are creating a `Flux` of strings at `Flux.fromIterable(str)`. What you need to do is put the string into a wrapper class or send a `Mono` of a list. See, e.g., [Reactive Programming: Spring WebFlux: How to build a chain of micro-service calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858717/reactive-programming-spring-webflux-how-to-build-a-chain-of-micro-service-call/60907153#60907153)

Comment: Thanks it worked, i create new class and created list variable. with the reference of class was able to hit the API.